# JBoss 7.1 deployment issue : InitialContextFactory lookup failure

Tags: java, spring, deployment, jboss, jndi

I have a few Spring message listeners that use the following "jndiTemplate" :

```
<bean id="jnditemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">remote://127.0.0.1:4447</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">xyz</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">xyz123</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have added the user xyz using add-user.bat having guest role and in Application Realm.
However, when I deploy my app am getting the following in the logs:

```
02:02:29,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
02:02:29,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.<AppNameDeleted>.war:main" from Service Module Loader
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(InitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:64)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:664) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.createInitialContext(JndiTemplate.java:136) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.getContext(JndiTemplate.java:103) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:85) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
```

Any ideas as to what could be going wrong? I've already spent more than a day on this one.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Trishul

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting `java.naming.factory.url.pkgs` property also? value `org.jboss.ejb.client.naming`. If that doesn't help you might need to crank up the logging and try to see what fails.

Comment: you could test first without spring if it works or not. Also, you could try what is suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17827910/365237)

Comment: adding the java.naming.factory.url.pkgs didn't help. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I was finally able to get past this issue. I had to include the file jboss-client.jar located at <JBOSS HOME>\bin\client in my app's WEB-INF\lib.. I still don't know why this works since its mentioned in the accompanying README that **This jar should be used
with standalone clients only, not with deployments are that deployed to an AS7 instance**. Sometimes 'RTFM' can be dangerous it seems !